# How to remove #define use in C++ array constant?

Tags: c++

Having this code:

```
#define GREEN 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
#define RED   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f

const float colors[] = {
    RED, GREEN, RED, RED,
};
```

I can not think of a better (typed) way to create colors, without using the `#define`. Is it a better way? Also, having the C++11 standard in mind.

UPDATE:
Full example of code using this kind of define, https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/src/3ee6f3dd04a76a1628201d2543a85e444bae8d25/Tut%2005%20Objects%20in%20Depth/OverlapNoDepth.cpp?at=default

Comment: Why don't you use a struct/class to define your Color object ?

Comment: your `#define` doesn't make much sense. You're defining color as 3 comma-separated values? Your code will actually be `const float colors[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};` Is this what you want?

Comment: @icepack: it's obviously red/green/blue intensities, so yes it is what Zhen wants.

Comment: @TonyD First, if that's the case, what does `0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f` mean? A greener green? Second, the usage of these defines is problematic also since they are just poured into an array without any semantic separation between the triplets.

Comment: @icepack: 1) why does 5.0f have to mean anything?  It can be - and by implication is - an invalid value in this context.  2) that may not be problematic to Zhen... indeed, it may match some rendering APIs he wants to call with the data.  I'm not saying it's pretty, but he's not asking either.  The question is whether there's a neater approach than the `#define`s - I can't think of one for pre-C++11 code, and don't know C++11 very well yet.

Comment: @icepack yes, it is I want, Is for a opengl like color buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do, but to create a list of colors I would do it like this :

```
#include <vector>

class color {
public:
  color(float r, float g, float b)
    : m_red(r), m_green(b), m_blue(b) { }

  float m_red;
  float m_green;
  float m_blue;
};

const auto red   = color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
const auto green = color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
const auto blue  = color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

int main {

  auto colors = std::vector<color>();
  colors.push_back(red);
  colors.push_back(green);
  colors.push_back(blue);
  colors.push_back(red);
  ...
}
```

**Edit**
As juanchopanza suggested it, I initialized the floats in the constructor initialization list.

Comment: I would +1 this if you had initialized the `floats` in the constructor initialization list instead of assigning values in the constructor's body.

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference here, @juan. `float`s are POD types.

Comment: Good point, I wrote this a bit quickly ! even with the same result, it's better to make good habits.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't care if the generated code is the same, I see no good reason to set values in the constructor body here.

Answer (score 3):

As Elasticboy suggested, do something like this:

```
struct Color {
   float R;
   float G;
   float B;
};
```

And now, create constants:

```
const Color Red = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
const Color Green = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
```

and so on...

Comment: If this is C++, there is no need for that `typedef`.

Comment: Well, no need, but it doesn't hurt, either.

Comment: Yeah, it does. It makes you wonder about whether the person who wrote the code knows C++.

Comment: I am refreshing on C++, too much C# in the past years ;)

Comment: But, How you define a the colors Array? It should be a float[], not a Color[].

Comment: @Zhen I think you don't understand it fully: every member of `Color` is a float. You'll need to access the members in the struct to get the values.

Comment: @bash.d I think he needs a packed `float[]` buffer for an API

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enum` here. e.g.

```
typedef enum color
{
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
} color;
```

alternatively you can assign default values to the colors also. e.g

```
typedef enum color
{
    RED=1, GREEN=5, BLUE=7
} color;
```

the only thing you have to keep in mind is that these are named integer constants. float values are not allowed here.

Comment: If he uses enum that he won't be able to set the RGB colors.